# Select a valid choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. What i'm trying to do is to show some JSON response value which i converted into tuples to show in the choicefield of my Django form.

This is how i'm creating the tuples

```
usernamelist = []
useremaillist = []
for userobject in userobjects:
    username = userobject['somevalue']
    email = userobject['somevalue']
    useremaillist.append(email)
    usernamelist.append(username)
user_tuple = zip(usernamelist,useremaillist)
```

This is my form

```
class UserSelectForm(forms.Form):
    users = forms.ChoiceField(label="Select user")
```

Then in my views i'm trying to put all these names into drop down list

```
selectform = UserSelectForm()
selectform.fields['users'].choices = user_tuple
```

its successfully showing but when i try to submit my form i'm getting Select a valid choice is not one of the available choices error.

This is where i'm trying to get the drop down selected value from submitted form

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'preview' in request.POST:
    selectform = UserSelectForm(request.POST)
    if selectform.is_valid():
        user_email = selectform.cleaned_data['users']
        print user_email
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: You really need to actually provide the choices in the form, you can't add them in the view and expect it to work for every instance of the form (You're using a different form in the bottom snippet)

Comment: i'm generating the choices in the views using API calls and JSON response i'm not getting these choices from database either. How to resolve this problem any different approaches?

Comment: You've not posted the minimal code needed to reproduce your problem. Please edit your post to do so.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - They have, the choices never get set for the form instance in the last code snippet

Comment: @Sayse the OP mentions api calls and JSON - I assume ajax calls here - but the relevant code is nowhere in sight.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to manually decide the choices then you should include them as a requirement for the initializer for the form

```
class UserSelectForm()
     def __init__(self, choices, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['users'].choices = choices
```

Then call it with the choices

```
UserSelectForm(user_tuple, request.POST or None)
```